# Sending data using Sockets from a C# application to a Lua application

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, lua

This function in my C# application will send the letter U to the lua application on another PC:

```
private void drive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.180");
    IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1337);
    soc.Connect(remote);

    byte[] commands = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("U");
    soc.Send(commands);
}
```

This is the small script in lua that will receive the commands from teh C# application and write them to serial (It's working fine, I tried it by sending character using netcat and everything worked fine.)

```
local socket = require("socket")
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 1337))

wserial=io.open("/dev/ttyATH0","w")

while 1 do
  local client = server:accept()
  client:settimeout(10)

  local line, err = client:receive()

  if not err then client:
    wserial:write(line)
  end

  wserial:flush()
  client:close()
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not receiving any data...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the answer was to change my code in C# to the following:

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient("192.168.1.4", 1337);
string cmd = "U\n";
byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));            
tcp.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

Beware

```
string cmd = "U\n";
```

You MUST add the new line character or it will not work.

Comment: Which is in the [manual](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive): `socket.receive()` has a `pattern` parameter, specified as such: _"'*l': reads a line of text from the socket. The line is terminated by a LF character (ASCII 10), optionally preceded by a CR character (ASCII 13). The CR and LF characters are not returned. This is the default pattern;"_

Comment: For emphasis: *"This is the default pattern"*